# windows update - strange behaviour using up all CPU

Tags: windows, windows-update, troubleshooting

I have a windows 2008R2 server which has had windows update go mad.  Last night it started pegging the CPU @ 100% and using 1GB RAM.  Killing the Windows Update service took the CPU and MEM back to normal but i am struggling to find the root cause.  The behaviour persists after reboots and switching the service back on will cause the CPU to go back to 100%

Windows Update is set to download only and I patch manually,  I haven't patched Novembers updates yet.

After some googling, I looked in the CBS.log file but its beyond my understanding.  The entries around the time it started acting up are below.

```
2014-11-20 18:45:06, Info                  CBS    Session: 30409970_438815240 initialized by client RMT.
2014-11-20 18:45:06, Info                  CBS    Session: 30409970_438815240 finalized. Reboot required: no [HRESULT = 0x00000000 - S_OK]
2014-11-20 18:47:10, Info                  CBS    Session: 30409970_1686451038 initialized by client RMT.
2014-11-20 18:47:10, Info                  CBS    Session: 30409970_1686451038 finalized. Reboot required: no [HRESULT = 0x00000000 - S_OK]
2014-11-20 18:57:11, Info                  CBS    Reboot mark refs incremented to: 1
2014-11-20 18:57:11, Info                  CBS    Scavenge: Starts
2014-11-20 18:57:11, Info                  CSI    00000009@2014/11/20:18:57:11.477 CSI Transaction @0x36c830 initialized for deployment engine {d16d444c-56d8-11d5-882d-0080c847b195} with flags 00000002 and client id [10]"TI6.0_0:0/"
2014-11-20 18:57:11, Info                  CBS    Scavenge: Begin CSI Store
2014-11-20 18:57:20, Info                  CSI    0000000a Performing 1 operations; 1 are not lock/unlock and follow:
Scavenge (8): flags: 00000017
2014-11-20 18:57:20, Info                  CSI    0000000b Store coherency cookie matches last scavenge cookie, skipping scavenge.
2014-11-20 18:57:20, Info                  CSI    0000000c ICSITransaction::Commit calling IStorePendingTransaction::Apply - coldpatching=FALSE applyflags=7
2014-11-20 18:57:20, Info                  CSI    0000000d Creating NT transaction (seq 2), objectname [6]"(null)"
2014-11-20 18:57:20, Info                  CSI    0000000e Created NT transaction (seq 2) result 0x00000000, handle @0x94
2014-11-20 18:57:21, Info                  CSI    0000000f@2014/11/20:18:57:21.194 CSI perf trace: CSIPERF:TXCOMMIT;48025
2014-11-20 18:57:21, Info                  CBS    Scavenge: Completed, disposition: 0X1
2014-11-20 18:57:21, Info                  CSI    00000010@2014/11/20:18:57:21.203 CSI Transaction @0x36c830 destroyed
2014-11-20 18:57:21, Info                  CBS    Reboot mark refs: 0
2014-11-20 18:57:21, Info                  CBS    Idle processing thread terminated normally
2014-11-20 18:57:21, Info                  CBS    Ending the TrustedInstaller main loop.
2014-11-20 18:57:21, Info                  CBS    Starting TrustedInstaller finalization.
2014-11-20 18:57:22, Info                  CBS    Ending TrustedInstaller finalization.
2014-11-21 16:56:22, Info                  CBS    Starting TrustedInstaller initialization.
2014-11-21 16:56:22, Info                  CBS    Loaded Servicing Stack v6.1.7601.17514 with Core: C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_678566b7ddea04a5\cbscore.dll
2014-11-21 16:56:23, Info                  CSI    00000001@2014/11/21:16:56:23.637 WcpInitialize (wcp.dll version 0.0.0.6) called (stack @0x7fedc5ae94d @0x7fedc8d9839 @0x7fedc8a34d3 @0xff1be97c @0xff1bd799 @0xff1bdb2f)
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CBS    Could not load SrClient DLL from path: SrClient.dll.  Continuing without system restore points.
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CSI    00000002@2014/11/21:16:56:24.080 WcpInitialize (wcp.dll version 0.0.0.6) called (stack @0x7fedc5ae94d @0x7fedc926806 @0x7fedc8f2a9c @0x7fedc8a35a9 @0xff1be97c @0xff1bd799)
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CSI    00000003@2014/11/21:16:56:24.094 WcpInitialize (wcp.dll version 0.0.0.6) called (stack @0x7fedc5ae94d @0x7fee98d8728 @0x7fee98d8856 @0xff1be474 @0xff1bd7de @0xff1bdb2f)
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CBS    Ending TrustedInstaller initialization.
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CBS    Starting the TrustedInstaller main loop.
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CBS    TrustedInstaller service starts successfully.
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CBS    SQM: Initializing online with Windows opt-in: False
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CBS    SQM: Cleaning up report files older than 10 days.
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CBS    SQM: Requesting upload of all unsent reports.
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CBS    SQM: Failed to start upload with file pattern: C:\Windows\servicing\sqm\*_std.sqm, flags: 0x2 [HRESULT = 0x80004005 - E_FAIL]
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CBS    SQM: Failed to start standard sample upload. [HRESULT = 0x80004005 - E_FAIL]
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CBS    SQM: Queued 0 file(s) for upload with pattern: C:\Windows\servicing\sqm\*_all.sqm, flags: 0x6
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CBS    SQM: Warning: Failed to upload all unsent reports. [HRESULT = 0x80004005 - E_FAIL]
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CBS    No startup processing required, TrustedInstaller service was not set as autostart, or else a reboot is still pending.
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CBS    NonStart: Checking to ensure startup processing was not required.
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CSI    00000004 IAdvancedInstallerAwareStore_ResolvePendingTransactions (call 1) (flags = 00000004, progress = NULL, phase = 0, pdwDisposition = @0x183fbf0
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CSI    00000005 Creating NT transaction (seq 1), objectname [6]"(null)"
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CSI    00000006 Created NT transaction (seq 1) result 0x00000000, handle @0x1cc
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CSI    00000007@2014/11/21:16:56:24.395 CSI perf trace: CSIPERF:TXCOMMIT;81226
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CBS    NonStart: Success, startup processing not required as expected.
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CBS    Startup processing thread terminated normally
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CSI    00000008 CSI Store 3251744 (0x0000000000319e20) initialized
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CBS    Session: 30410156_358019406 initialized by client RMT.
2014-11-21 16:56:24, Info                  CBS    Session: 30410156_358019406 finalized. Reboot required: no [HRESULT = 0x00000000 - S_OK]
2014-11-21 16:58:28, Info                  CBS    Session: 30410156_1599414730 initialized by client RMT.
2014-11-21 16:58:28, Info                  CBS    Session: 30410156_1599414730 finalized. Reboot required: no [HRESULT = 0x00000000 - S_OK]
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, even if "download only" Windows Update still "checks" things, particularly at startup.  What seems to be happening here is it is finding problems in the process of doing so.  Unfortunately, the problem that seems to match most closely based on the errors in the log above is this one:  http://blogs.technet.com/b/roplatforms/archive/2011/04/28/installation-failures-cbs-store-corruptions-uncommon-issues-and-troubleshooting.aspx.

You might also try searching on "TrustedInstaller 100% CPU Windows 2008 r2" to see other options that might be applicable (I am new so can only post a couple of URLs or I would list them here, as well).

Best of luck.